# php regex match possible accented characters

Tags: php, regex, search, special-characters

I found alot of questions about this, but none of those helped me with my especific problem. The situation: I want to search a `string` with something like `"blablebli"` and be able to find a match with all possible accented variations of that (`"blablebli"`, `"blábleblí"`, `"blâblèbli"`, etc...) in an text.

I already made a workaround to to the opposite (find a word without possible accents that i wrote). But i can't figure it out a way to implement what i want.

Here is my working code. (the relevant part, this was part of a foreach so we are only seeing a single word search):

```
$word="something";
$word = preg_quote(trim($word)); //Just in case
$word2 = $this->removeAccents($word); // Removed all accents
if(!empty($word)) {
    $sentence = "/(".$word.")|(".$word2.")/ui"; // Now I'm checking with and without accents.
    if (preg_match($sentence, $content)){
        echo "found";
    }
}
```

And my `removeAccents()` function (i'm not sure if i covered all possible accents with that `preg_replace()`. So far it's working. I would appreciate if someone check if i'm missing anything):

```
function removeAccents($string)
{
    return preg_replace('/[\`\~\']/', '', iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string));
}
```

**What i'm trying to avoid:**

- I know i could check my `$word` and replace all `a` for `[aàáãâä]` and
  same thing with other letters, but i dont know... it seens a litle
  overkill.
- And sure i could use my own `removeAccents()` function in my `if`
  statement to check the `$content` without accents, something like:

  ```
  if (preg_match($sentence, $content) || preg_match($sentence, removeAccents($content)))
  ```

But my problem with that second situation is i want to hightlight the word found after the match. So i can't change my `$content`.

Is there any way to improve my `preg_match()` to include possible accented characters? Or should i use my first option above?

Comment: Am I groundhog daying or did you ask this yesterday as well?

Comment: Hahaha yea i deleted that one, sorry. After 17 hours it had like ~25 viewers and no comments or anything. It was going to oblivion =/

Comment: Apply `removeAccents` on the source string, use `preg_match` with `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` option to get the index of the match *(or `strpos`)*, use `mb_substr` to make your replacement in the original string. Or use the first way that is not overkill at all and can easily be done with `strtr`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks. But, if i understood what you said, i'm afraid that wont work 100%. After `removeAccents()` being applied to any string, I can't really guarantee that the number of letters will be the same. IE: `$content = "i'ts a sample"` will return `"its a sample"`, making the indexes different.

Comment: Atm, i'm using the first solution i mentioned, but the reason i don't liked it is this code (as i said) is part of a `foreach`. The real search is looking for a sentence inside alot of texts. I'm breaking the search sentence to words and showing to the user possible results based in how many words are matching (and highlighting those words).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte without the preg_replace(), something like `"Olá que horas são?"` will return `"Ol'a que horas s~ao?"`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte returns "C"

Comment: @Clyff: That is why iconv returns the wrong result. Add `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.UTF-8');` before `iconv`. (or `es_ES.UTF-8` or what you want)

Comment: I Used both. I even made a new file, put only setlocate, and the iconv. Still same result.

Comment: @Cliff: are you sure your string is UTF8? try this one: `iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT'...` instead.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I'm typing the string before call the function, so i guess i can't go wrong... can i? `$string = "Olá que horas são?"; var_dump(removeAccents($string));`

Comment: If you use linux, type `locale -a` in the terminal to know available locales on your server and use one of them for LC_CTYPE. (except C or POSIX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone, but i will end it up using my first sugestion i made in my question. And thanks again @CasimiretHippolyte for your patience, and making me realize that isn't that overkill as i thought.

Here is the final code I'm using (first the functions):

```
function removeAccents($string)
{
    return preg_replace('/[\x{0300}-\x{036f}]/u', '', Normalizer::normalize($string, Normalizer::FORM_KD));
}

function addAccents($string)
{
    $array1 = array('a', 'c', 'e', 'i' , 'n', 'o', 'u', 'y');
    $array2 = array('[aàáâãäå]','[cçćĉċč]','[eèéêë]','[iìíîï]','[nñ]','[oòóôõö]','[uùúûü]','[yýÿ]');

    return str_replace($array1, $array2, strtolower($string));
}
```

And:

```
$word="something";
$word = preg_quote(trim($word)); //Just in case
$word2 = $this->addAccents($this->removeAccents($word)); //check all possible accents
if(!empty($word)) {
    $sentence = "/(".$word.")|(".$word2.")/ui"; // Now I'm checking my normal word and the possible variations of it.
    if (preg_match($sentence, $content)){
        echo "found";
    }
}
```

Btw, im covering all possible accents from my country (and some others). You should check if you need to improve the `addAccents()` function before use it.

Answer (score 2):

I would decompose the string, this makes it easier to remove the offending characters, something along the lines:

```
<?php

// Convert unicode input to NFKD form.
$str = Normalizer::normalize("blábleblí", Normalizer::FORM_KD);

// Remove all combining characters (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character).
var_dump(preg_replace('/[\x{0300}-\x{036f}]/u', "", $str));
```

Comment: Nice, I will definitely use that instead of `iconv`, thank you!